# My app working on android 2.2 and android 2.3.3 emulators but not on my phone galaxy s android 2.3.5 / Read facebook,twitter contacts?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-2.3

i have a problem with my app ,

In egypt they are going to add extra digit to mobile numbers to expand , so i made an app to modify the existing numbers to the new one.

So basically  i read all phone numbers , based on some conditions i manipulate them and save the new data,

Iam working on eclipse with adt plugin , i have tried the app on emulator 2.2 , and emulator 2.3 and is working very fine and modify all contacts.

but when i transfered on my mobile galaxy s android 2.3.5 , it runs without saving the new contact data , i even debugged to see the flow , it works normal gets all numbers modify them and save them without errors , but contacts are not updated.

Is there a certain reason , can you give me more ideas ?

i want to provide some more info , i have installed froyo 2.2 on my mobile and still won't save the new contact number , although it is working very good on the emulator, i save the contact this way :

```
    ContentResolver cr2 = getContentResolver();

                    String where = Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND "
                            + String.valueOf(Phone.TYPE) + " = ? ";
                    String[] params = new String[] { id,
                            String.valueOf(type) };


ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops=new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();


                    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                            .newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                            .withSelection(where, params)
                            .withValue(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA,
                                    phoneNumber).build());



                    try {
                        cr2.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY,ops);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

**Ok Guys , Sorry iam just new to android , but i found the mistake and i modified the code to be :**

```
ContentResolver cr2 = getContentResolver();

                    String where = Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +Data.MIMETYPE + "='" +
                            Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'" + " AND "
                            + String.valueOf(Phone.TYPE) + " = ? ";
                    String[] params = new String[] { id,
                            String.valueOf(type) };

                    // Cursor phoneCur = managedQuery(Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    // null, where, params, null);

                    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

                    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                            .newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                            .withSelection(where, params).withValue(
                                    Phone.NUMBER,
                                    phoneNumber).build());



                    try {
                        cr2.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                        count++;
                        System.out.println(phoneNumber);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

**So Technincally i added the mimetype , and i used to update phone.data so i changed that also to phone.number , now it is working ok on 2.2 / 2.3.5 , so i guess this question is closed , but i have one more thing to ask , the read contacts doesn't include facebook or twitter contacts , is there anyway to read all contacts to update them all including facebook and twitter ????**

Comment: I am facing a similar problem with Android 2.3.5, it doesnt open, create or read database, not sure yet. My app should read database that is included in the app and should be copied from assets folder to data/data/packagename/databases/, the app works fine on almost all Android versions but not 2.3.5, any ideas? I believe you have more experience in this version now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing: just change the project-properties file and edit `target=android-10` and then try...